# add corner box to highlight (typed.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented typed.js, wanted to duplicate this [highlighted text with excel-like box at corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVLUq.jpg)

I currently have the text typing out highlighted and implemented a SVG for the box in html but I can't seem to get it right at the corner.

```
#typed {
line-height: 1;
display: inline-block;
color: #111517;
background: rgba(0, 187, 255, 0.41);
box-shadow: 5px 0 0 rgba(0, 187, 255, 0.41), -5px 0 0 rgba(0, 187, 255, 0.41);
padding: 2px 0; }
```

Comment: show your html please

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```css
.typed {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #111517;
  background: rgba(0, 187, 255, 0.41);
  box-shadow:0 5px 0 #fff,
            5px 0 0 #fff, 
            5px 5px 0 red;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="typed">
  Some text
</div>
```

Or use pseudo element to create it:

```css
.typed {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #111517;
  background: rgba(0, 187, 255, 0.41);
  position:relative;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
.typed:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:100%;
  background:red;
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="typed">
  Some text
</div>
```